# Trying to copy char array to struct crashing

Tags: c, arrays, swift, struct, bluetooth-lowenergy

*(to preface this my C is terrible)*

I'm trying to send a string from iOS to a BLE device. I encode the string in swift and write it like this:

```
func sendUserName(userName: String) {
    let bytes: [UInt8] = Array(userName.utf8)

    print(bytes.count)

    let data = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)
    capsenseLedBoard!.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: userIdCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
}
```

I send in this string `"THISISATEST123456789"` and this line `print(bytes.count)` prints out `20`.

---

I recieve the data on the BLE device like this and pass it to the below `userDidConnect` function:

```
userDidConnect((char *)wrReqParam->handleValPair.value.val);
```

---

I have a `struct` called `Event` that looks like this:

```
struct Event {
    char time[20];   // The time in ISO 1601 format
    char name[3];    // The two character name of the event. See header for declarations.
    char userId[20]; // The userId of the connected user if one is present.
    struct Event* next;
};
```

---

I have a global variable declared like this:

```
char currentlyConnectedUserID[20];
```

---

I then have an enqueue function that looks like this:

```
/**
 Creates a new Event and adds to the linked list.

 @param time   The time in ISO 8601 format.
 @param name   The name descriptor of the event ("VS", "VO", etc.)
 @param userId The id of the user who is currently connect (if they are connected).
 */
    void enqueueEvent(char time[20], char name[3], char userId[20]) {

    struct Event* temp = (struct Event*)malloc(sizeof(struct Event));
    strncpy( temp->time,   time, 20);
    strncpy( temp->name,   name, 3);
    strncpy( temp->userId, userId, 20);
    temp->next = NULL;

    if(front == NULL && rear == NULL) {
        front = rear = temp;
        return;
    }
    rear->next = temp;
    rear = temp;
}
```

---

I have a function that accepts a new userId and then creates a new Event off of it and adds it to the linked list..well this is what it's suppose to do:

```
void userDidConnect(char *userId)
{
    size_t destination_size = sizeof(userId);
    snprintf(currentlyConnectedUserID, destination_size, "%s", userId);
    //enqueueEvent("2007-03-01T13:00:20", "UC", currentlyConnectedUserID);

    showMessageInUART(currentlyConnectedUserID, sizeof(currentlyConnectedUserID));
}
```

---

Currently if I run the `userDidConnect` method above I'm able to printout the `currentlyConnectedUserID` properly. However, if I uncomment out this line:

```
//enqueueEvent("2007-03-01T13:00:20", "UC", currentlyConnectedUserID);
```

I get a "crash". I'm doing this in a fairly obscure IDE (PSoC Creator from Cypress) so I don't see any error logs or IDE crash logs. The only way I can tell is that the `showMessageInUART` is never called, so I know it has to be that line.

I'm able to successfully create and enqueue a new Event if I do this:

```
enqueueEvent("2007-03-01T13:00:20", "UC", "1234567891234567891");
```

My only thought is that maybe the size of the array is wrong? Maybe? Or perhaps there is some trailing `\0` that is screwing things up?

---

Suggestion updates:

I've tried doing this:

```
size_t destination_size = strlen(userId) + 1;
```

Which gives the correct value into `currentlyConnectedUserID` however enqueueing still causes a crash.

--

I've replaced `strcpy` with `strncpy` which is still causing a crash ;(

--

Tried this to ensure I didn't overflow which still didn't work:

```
sprintf(currentlyConnectedUserID, "%.19s", userId);
```

---

**UPDATE**

I updated my enqueue to look like this since don't have breakpoints:

```
void enqueueEvent(char time[20], char name[3], char userId[20]) {

    UART_UartPutString("start enqueue");

    struct Event* temp = (struct Event*)malloc(sizeof(struct Event));

    UART_UartPutString("1");

    strncpy( temp->time,   time, 20);

    UART_UartPutString("2");

    strncpy( temp->name,   name, 3);

    UART_UartPutString("3");

    strncpy( temp->userId, userId, 20);

    UART_UartPutString("4");

    temp->next = NULL;

    UART_UartPutString("5");

    if(front == NULL && rear == NULL) {
        front = rear = temp;
        return;
    }
    rear->next = temp;
    rear = temp;
}
```

This line is crashing:

`strncpy( temp->time,   time, 20);`

aka we never make it here: `UART_UartPutString("2");`

If I call this same function from `main` it works fine. Any idea why it would be crashing here when called from a different method?

Comment: I suspect `userDidConnect` is not doing what you want. `userId` is a pointer, so `sizeof(userId)` is going to return 4 on 32-bit machines and 8 on 64-bit machines. If `userId` points to a string, I bet you want the string length instead.

Comment: @yano I've tried replacing `sizeof` with `strlen` which still give me the correct conversion to `currentlyConnectedUserID` however enqueuing still crashes :(

Comment: Then `sizeof(userId) + 1` will return 5 or 9 depending on your architecture. My guess is you have string problems, but there's not enough code here to know for sure. What are you passing in to `userDidConnect`?

Comment: @yano I know that userId is going to be a valid string, updated to use `strlen` which is working in converting `*userId` param to `currentlyConnectedUserID` however trying to enqueue still crashes :(

Comment: Anytime you overwrite a buffer in C, you exercise _undefined behavior_, which means all bets are off after that. You may get lucky and things will work, it may crash in a seemingly random place. Just because things are crashing in `enqueueEvent` doesn't necessarily mean that's where the error is. That could just be exposing an error from earlier.

Comment: @yano this maybe a naive assumption on my part but if I comment out the enqueue call everything continues to work fine. Perhaps it's my enqueue function itself that's wrong?

Comment: Based on what you're passing to `enqueueEvent` I see no problem. You're passing strings of length 19, 2, 19,, which will fit into buffers of 20, 3, 20 (including null bytes). That's why I think the real problem is somewhere before that. Also, in `enqueueEvent`, make sure `malloc` isn't returning NULL. If it is, that will cause a crash as well. Also don't know what `front` or `rear` are. There's simply not enough code here to know what the problem is, thus all my guessing.

Comment: Please post an MVCE. Have you tried stepping through with a debugger? Does it crash in exactly the same place every time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124355/discussion-between-random-and-yano).

Answer (score 1):

The strcpy funtion Copies the C string pointed by source into the array pointed by destination, **including the terminating null character** (and stopping at that point).
Therefore, I propose you to change the `enqueueEvent` funtion, using `strncpy` instead of dangerous `strcpy` as :

```
void enqueueEvent(char time[20], char name[3], char userId[20]) {

    struct Event* temp = (struct Event*)malloc(sizeof(struct Event));
    strncpy( temp->time,   time,20);
    strncpy( temp->name,   name,3);
    strncpy( temp->userId, userId,20);
    temp->next = NULL;

    if(front == NULL && rear == NULL) {
        front = rear = temp;
        return;
    }
    rear->next = temp;
    rear = temp;
}
```

Change also the allocation of `temp` pointer from local stack of the `enqueueEvent` function to global level because the pointer allocation is vanished when going outside of the function.

Comment: should I do the recommend changes from the first comment on my question as well?

Comment: be careful with `strncpy`. It does not guarantee to copy a terminating `'\0'`, so while it may not overflow the buffer during the copy, you can run into trouble down the road accessing/modifying those strings if they have no null terminator

Comment: Another point to investigate is the `currentlyConnectedUserID` value : how are you sure that it is less than 20 char length (including \0) ?

Comment: @P.Bra I'm converting a 19 character string into `char *` that's getting passed into the `userDidConnect` function. I've also tried, 18 characters, and 20 characters. The IDE i'm using sucks and there is no real easy way to get the length of it :(

Comment: To be sure that you don't write more than 20 including \0, you can simplify by using the "%.19s" format with `sprintf` statement (instead of snprintf): `sprintf(currentlyConnectedUserID, "%.19s", userId);` 
What about `front` `rear` pointers ? because `temp` pointer is allocated on the local stack.

Comment: @P.Bra gave that a whirl and it still didn't :,(

Comment: @random I think that your problem is probably coming from the `front` and `rear` pointers assignation which are taken on the local stack of the function `enqueueEvent`, then are vanished when you go outside of the function. I propose you to comment out all the code related to mechanism linked pointers you have designed and retest again.

Comment: @P.Bra i think you're right with my `malloc` being nil